# how to found a match in pusher or pubnub like quizup app

Tags: pusher, pubnub

How can match two opponents. Lets say i have 10 opponents online and ready for match. I assume being online and ready for match are two subscribed channels after user interactions. Shortly i want to achieve Quizup iphone app like system.

how to found a match

Comment: Hi Vishnu we have some blog posts which will help you out.  Give us a moment and we'll post the links.

Answer (score 1):

## PubNub Player Match Making like QuizUp App

When it comes to multiplayer gaming, matchmaking is essential for matching up two or more players in a multiplayer game. In this blog post, we’ll walk you through our matchmaking algorithm for random matchmaking (matching up two random users).

### Matchmaking Algorithm: *Random Matchmaking*

Adding a *"Find Match"* Button.

> Learn how **[Matchmaking for Multiplayer Games with PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/random-matchmaking-multiplayer-games/)** can be accomplished.

[image: Random Matchmaking Algorithm Find Match Button]

Check out the full matchmaking demo on CodePen. In the next chapter, we’ll make matchmaking a smarter by adding skill levels into the mix, then we’ll enable users to challenge one another.

### Matchmaking Algorithm: *Skill-based Matchmaking*

> Learn how **[Matchmaking Algorithm: Skill-based Matchmaking](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/skill-based-matchmaking-multiplayer-games-tutorial/)** can be accomplished.

[image: Skill Based Multiplayer Matchmaking]

We can show the skill level of each user in the list of online users. The same state object we defined earlier is returned as the data property of the user object when the `presence` event is fired from `pubnub.subscribe`.

Comment: Hi, 
but i think the matching in quizup app is server side not client side.
player request server for match and server return appropriate data to client devices.

Comment: Server-side player pairing is actually simpler!  Although more expensive architecturally to build a server-side player grouping because you need distributed components like load-balancers, databases and app logic servers dedicated to user paring.  This becomes expensive.  It's much lower cost to have the client-side negotiate game pairings.  However the method for server-side pairing starts with collecting `"online-users"`.  Then keeping a `"state"` of users for `"ready-to-play"` or `"player-in-game"` status.  You can then pair groupings of users and signal via PubNub their game room channel.